# php: регулярное выражение для preg_split()

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пишу регулярное выражение для preg_split(), чтобы строка разбивалась по пробелам + всем возможным знакам препинания. Пока оно выглядит так:

```
$pattern = "/[\s,;.\!\-\?\:\(\)]+/";
```

1. Как добавить в выражение длинное тире, все возможные кавычки и т.д. (может, ещё какие знаки препинания забыл)?
2. `preg_split()` с таким выражением добавляет в конец массива пустой элемент. Понятно, что его можно потом вырезать, но это решение мне не нравится. Как поправить выражение, чтобы не было пустого элемента?

Спасибо!

Comment: `trim` + `/\W+/u` вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1. Необходимо определиться какой точно результат нужен. Если только знаки препинания, то придется полностью перечислять в символьном классе все желаемые символы, в том числе `длинное тире, все возможные кавычки и т.д.` - нет универсального символьного класса для описания этого.
   2. Если нужно достигнуть результата в котором делится по всем литералам, которые не являются пробелами и буквами, то есть символьный класс `[:punct:]`. В регулярном выражении это будет выглядеть так:

      ```
      /[\s[:punct:]]+/
      ```
2. Для исключения пустых элементов достаточно передать флаг `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` в функцию [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)

   ```
   preg_split( "/[\s[:punct:]]+/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY )
   ```

   http://ideone.com/iZjYU0

Comment: /[\s[:punct:]]+/ не работает, увы(( возвращает целую строку как она есть

Comment: Извините, при копипасте нечаянно потерял одно двоеточие. Смотрите пример на IDEone. Если так и не работает - приведите пример строки.